# how to find largest element in a linked list?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have below program to define a Linked list:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data  = data
        self.nxt = None
class lnklst:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None

    def addNode(self,value):
        nuNde = Node(value)
        if self.start is None:
           self.start = nuNde
        else:
            p = self.start
            while p.nxt != None:
                p = p.nxt
            p.nxt = nuNde

    def viewNde(self):
        tp = self.start
        while tp is not None:
            print(tp.data, end=' <--> ')
            tp = tp.nxt

def highEle(self):
    a = self.start
    b = a.nxt
    while a:
        if a.data > b.data:
            a.data = b.data
        tmp = a.data
        a.data = self.start
        self.start = tmp
```

I am able to create linked list, and view the elements. However, the logic to find the largest element(`def highEle`) from the linked list is not working.

The logic to find the largest element as below:

```
- Take 2 pointers 'a' and 'b'.
- a = b
- Since, a = b, then b holds a.next
- Run a while loop until a is not None.
- Inside while loop, define a 'if' statement to check if `a.data > b.data`, then swap.
```

But the logic doesn't seems to be working. Please suggest.

Comment: You don't care whether `a.data > b.data`.  You care whether `b.data` is greater than the largest number you've found so far.  You need to track that in a different variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the largest number in the list.

```
    def highEle(self):
        sofar = 0
        a = self.start
        while a:
            if a.data > sofar:
                sofar = a.data
            a = a.next
        return sofar
```